# Cropping in the very last layer in autoencoder in keras

Tags: keras, crop, convolution, keras-layer, autoencoder

I have images of shape `391 x 400`. I attempted to use the autoencoder as described [here](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html).

Specifically, I have used the following code:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K

input_img = Input(shape=(391, 400, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format

x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

# at this point the representation is (4, 4, 8) i.e. 128-dimensional

x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

I am getting the following:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_37 to have shape (None, 392, 400, 1) but got array with shape (500, 391, 400, 1)
```

What I need: a layer that would drop/crop/reshape the last layer from `392 x 400` to `391 x 400`.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a layer called `Cropping2D`. To crop the last layer from `392 x 400` to `391 x 400`, you can use it by:

```
cropped = Cropping2D(cropping=((1, 0), (0, 0)))(decoded)
autoencoder = Model(input_img, cropped)
```

The tuple `((1, 0), (0, 0))` means to crop 1 row from the top. If you want to crop from bottom, use `((0, 1), (0, 0))` instead. You can see the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#cropping2d) for more detailed description about the `cropping` argument.